# solving a problem using determinants

Tags: matrices, induction, recurrence-relations, determinant

> Let $(x_n)_{n\ge 0}$ be defined by the recurrence relation $x_{n+1} = ax_n + b x_{n-1}$ with $x_0=0$. Show that $x_n^2 - x_{n-1} x_{n+1}$ depends only on $b$ and $x_1$ but not on $a$.

One could show this easily using induction on n. For the induction step one can (for $n\ge 2$) show that $x_n^2 - x_{n-1} x_{n+1} = -b(x_{n-1}^2 - x_{n-2}x_n)$. However, the term $x_n^2 - x_{n-1}x_{n+1}$ seems like a determinant of a matrix, so I was wondering if this problem could be solved using determinants?

Comment: Hint: let $v_n:=\left(\begin{array}{c}x_n\\x_{n+1}\end{array}\right)$ so your induction step is equivalent to proving $|\begin{array}{cc}v_{n+1} & v_n\end{array}|=-b|\begin{array}{cc}
v_n & v_{n-1}\end{array}|$.

Comment: I wonder how did you find the inductive formula without using determinants. To solve this problem, I will find the general formula of $x_n$ by $n$. In this way, I need to consider two cases: whether the roots of the equation $t^2-at-b=0$ are different or not, since it will affect to the formula of $x_n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the answer that (I think) was likely intended for this question. The wording might've been slightly unclear.

Let $A = \begin{pmatrix}x_1 & 0\\
x_2 & x_1\end{pmatrix}$. Then note that by induction $\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1\\
b & a\end{pmatrix}^{n-1}A = \begin{pmatrix}x_n & x_{n-1}\\
x_{n+1} & x_n\end{pmatrix}$.

Taking determinants of both sides and manipulating yields the required result.

Answer (score 4):

Indeed it can. Write
$$
\begin{bmatrix}x_{n+1}\\x_{n}\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}x_{n} & x_{n-1}\\x_{n-1} & x_{n-2}\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}a\\b\end{bmatrix},
$$
then solve for $b$ using Cramer's rule.